# Javascript Array count of object based on condition and by object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i am trying to count object has value **added === true** by **child_name** witch javascript function useful please guide me ?

This is main Array this array has object under object has items and under items has another object key and value how to count object only if **added === true** by **child_name**

```
[
  {
    "id": 38,
    "items": {
      "Big Box": [
        [
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": false
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 37,
    "items": {
      "Drawers": [
        [
          {
            "id": 1108,
            "parent_name": "Drawers",
            "child_name": "Small "
          },
          {
            "id": 1109,
            "parent_name": "Drawers",
            "child_name": "Medium",
            "added": true
          },
          {
            "id": 1110,
            "parent_name": "Drawers",
            "child_name": "Large"
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Mirror": [
        [
          {
            "id": 1141,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Large",
            "added": false
          },
          {
            "id": 1142,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Small",
            "added": true
          },
          {
            "id": 1143,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Medium",
            "added": false
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "id": 1141,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Large"
          },
          {
            "id": 1142,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Small"
          },
          {
            "id": 1143,
            "parent_name": "Mirror",
            "child_name": "Medium",
            "added": true
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Stand": [
        [
          {
            "id": 1145,
            "parent_name": "Stand",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "id": 1145,
            "parent_name": "Stand",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "id": 1145,
            "parent_name": "Stand",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

output should like this count object by **child_name** and **added === true**

```
    [
      {
       "parent_name":"Big Box",
       "child_name":"",
       "count":2
      },
      {
       "parent_name":"Drawers",
       "child_name":"Medium",
       "count":1
      },
      {
       "parent_name":"Mirror",
       "child_name":"Small",
       "count":1
      },
      {
       "parent_name":"Mirror",
       "child_name":"Medium",
       "count":1
      },
      {
       "parent_name":"Stand",
       "child_name":"",
       "count":3
      }
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to know how to ask good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `reduce`. Here is my try:

```js
var data=[ { "id": 38, "items": { "Big Box": [ [ { "id": 1153, "parent_name": "Big Box", "child_name": "", "added": true } ], [ { "id": 1153, "parent_name": "Big Box", "child_name": "", "added": false } ], [ { "id": 1153, "parent_name": "Big Box", "child_name": "", "added": true } ] ] } }, { "id": 37, "items": { "Drawers": [ [ { "id": 1108, "parent_name": "Drawers", "child_name": "Small " }, { "id": 1109, "parent_name": "Drawers", "child_name": "Medium", "added": true }, { "id": 1110, "parent_name": "Drawers", "child_name": "Large" } ] ], "Mirror": [ [ { "id": 1141, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Large", "added": false }, { "id": 1142, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Small", "added": true }, { "id": 1143, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Medium", "added": false } ], [ { "id": 1141, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Large" }, { "id": 1142, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Small" }, { "id": 1143, "parent_name": "Mirror", "child_name": "Medium", "added": true } ] ], "Stand": [ [ { "id": 1145, "parent_name": "Stand", "child_name": "", "added": true } ], [ { "id": 1145, "parent_name": "Stand", "child_name": "", "added": true } ], [ { "id": 1145, "parent_name": "Stand", "child_name": "", "added": true } ] ] } }]

var result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {items})=>{
  Object.values(items).forEach(values=>{  
    values.flat().filter(g=>g.added).forEach((t,i,self)=>{
       key = `${t.parent_name}|${t.child_name}`
       acc[key]= {};
       acc[key]['parent_name'] = t.parent_name;
       acc[key]['child_name'] = t.child_name;
       acc[key]['count'] = self.filter(c=>c.added && c.child_name==t.child_name).length;
     });
  });
 return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

just iterate over all elements with `reduce` function and count pairs `child_name` and `parent_name`

```
const res = arr.reduce((agg, v) => { 
  for(const key in v.items) {
    if (!Array.isArray(v.items[key])) continue
    v.items[key].forEach(v => v.forEach(v => {
      if (typeof v !== 'object') return
      const value = {
        parent_name: v.parent_name,
        child_name: v.child_name,
        count: 1
      }
      const key = JSON.stringify(value)
      if (!agg[key]) 
        agg[key] = value 
      else
        agg[key].count++
    }))
  }
  return agg
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the items such as `"Big Box"` are array inside an array. You might like to simply that make it an array of objects and do this:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 38,
    "items": {
      "Big Box": [
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          },
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": false
          },
          {
            "id": 1153,
            "parent_name": "Big Box",
            "child_name": "",
            "added": true
          }
      ]
    }
 
  }
]
var output = [];
for(let i =0; i< data.length; i++)
for(var key in data[i].items){
  var x = data[0].items[key].filter(i=>i.added === true);
  var count = x.length;
  output.push({...x[0], ...{count}})
}
console.log(output)
```